# H2 database schema creation check

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, h2

I have H2 database generated on the-fly using Hibernate & Spring for my test-cases.
I have few weird errors, and I would like to know exactly how the schema looks like in H2. how the tables defined, and how the columns.
How can I generate this report during run-time ?

Comment: If you need a fine grain you should look up the persistence Table and Column annotations. You can specify and the control the names of things. Sometimes Hibernate has issues with bi-direction collections (...cannot get multiple Bags... is a common message if you're coming from Eclipselink or Toplink and you have complex relationships)

Answer (score 4):

If the schema is being deployed by Hibernate using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=true you could turn on trace logging for org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl. This would show you the DDL Hibernate is generating when it creates your schema.

Answer (score 2):

You could run the SQL statement `SCRIPT NODATA`.

To see the SQL statements that are run against the database, append `;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=2` to the database URL. This will write all SQL statements to the `.trace.db` file.

Comment: It works great, but actually I used it like that "SCRIPT NODATA TO 'create.sql'", that way I know exactly to where it saves it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what are the schemas getting generated on the fly. Simply add

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

With this you'll be able to debug.